# want to enable a combobox only when another combo is selected in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

There are two combo boxes and a button.I want a validation i.e. if "combo1" is selected then "combo2" should get enabled and when i select "combo2" then browse button should get enabled.

Comment: Have you coded anything up so far yet?

Answer (score 1):

Mabe something like that (insert text on first combobox):

The combobox2 and button must have this configs:

```
hidden:true,
disabled:true,
```

On combobox1:

```
listeners:{

change: function(combobox,newValue, eOpts){

 var combo2 = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#combo2ItemId')[0];
 var button = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#buttonItemId')[0];

 if(!Ext.isEmpty(newValue)) {
    combo2.setHidden(false).setDisabled(false);
    button.setHidden(true).setDisabled(true);
    }
 else {
    combo2.setHidden(true).setDisabled(true);
    button.setHidden(true).setDisabled(true);
    }
}
```

On combobox2:

```
listeners:{

change: function(combobox,newValue, eOpts){

 var button = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#buttonItemId')[0];

 if(!Ext.isEmpty(newValue)) {
    button.setHidden(false).setDisabled(false);
    }
 else {
    button.setHidden(true).setDisabled(true);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: thnks for your help @josei

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may want to disable the second combo and button when the page first shows.

Then You could listen for the change event for each combo and in your handler code disable\enable which ever controls you need to based on the values passed into the handler function arguments.